# Re-occurring kitchen drain backup

Tags: drain

We’ve had a ongoing issue with our kitchen sink gurgling and partially backing up.  Plumbers have been out three times to snake the line.  The first two were one year apart.  The latest snaking was 6 months ago.  Problem has resurfaced.  During the last plumber visit, he removed two close 90 elbows and replaced them with 45s to allow a faster and more direct drain path.  We also removed our garbage disposal after the second visit.  After the last plumber visit, we started using an enzyme cleaner once a month.  Nothing has worked.

How can a drain get partially blocked so quickly.  We don’t dump any oil down the drain.  The biggest issue is a long horizontal drain run, which I believe does not have enough slope.  The plumber also said he can’t really clean the entire 1.5 pipe cause his 1.5” cutter won’t go around one of the bends.  He admitted he cut a smaller hole in the bunk.  House is about 42 years old.  Ceiling is finished so I can’t see 95% of the long horizontal run.

I’m afraid my only solution is tearing up the textured drywall ceiling...I hate replacing and repairing drywall, especially finished textured one.

Any ideas?  Would pics or a schematic help?

---

Pipe is abs. 1.5”

Drain gurgles, but if I run the sink for awhile, it also starts to back up.  That would rule out a vent no?

Comment: Do any of your plumbers have video equipment that they can run down your pipe and see where/why it's clogging?

Comment: I agree with video. Pictures are a good start for here. What is the pipe made of under the sink? throughout the house? The 1.5  is the size of the pipe correct?

Comment: Trapped air caused by bad venting *or* bad slope could cause this.  There are also some partial blockages that resist snakes and enzymes.   Hard fat deposits built up over decades.  Kitchen sponges (usually down a toilet not a sink ... but who knows).   I had a similar issue in a kitchen island sink.  Fortunately everything was exposed in the unfinished basement.  The plumber said he could spend a whole day figuring it out, or just rip it all out and replace it properly in less than an hour. So we did that.  You may need to open the ceiling.  Video would be a good idea in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Gurgling can be due to a plugged vent rather than blockage in the liquid carrying line. You could take a hose up on the roof and run water down some vents. (Experts probably know a better way to detect and open up a clogged vent.)